# Passing the right parameters to variable methods in PHP

Tags: php, api-design

I'm setting up a PHP API that will expose functionality and vend data to my users, and I'm looking for an elegant way of passing to my functions the arguments that my users are "passing" to me. I can determine what method my users are calling ($_POST['method']) and depending on the method, zero or more arguments to the method. I validate them using a metadata array. For example:

```
$methods = array(
   'say_hello' => array('name'),
   'say_goodbye' => array(),
   'do_something' => array( 'foo', 'bar' )
);
```

I have corresponding functions for these:

```
function say_hello( $name ) { printf( "Hello, %s, $name ); }
function say_goodbye() { printf( "Goodbye!" ); }
function do_something( $foo, $bar ) { printf( "%d + %d = %d.", $foo, $bar, $foo+$bar ); }
```

When a POST comes in, I check that the method they're requesting is an array key of mine (so they're not passing in $_POST['method'] = 'exec' or anything nefarious), and I can do the actual call as:

```
$method = $_POST['method'];
$method(); // make the call
```

And knowing the method also allows me to determine what - if any - arguments should go into it:

```
$args = $methods[ $method ]; // an array of 0-2 items
```

But is there a good way for me to combine this without a big if-elseif-elseif-... ?

```
if( 'say_hello'==$method )
    $method( $_POST['name'] );
elseif( ... )
   ...
```

Something like Python's `myfunc(*args)` is what I'm looking to do, that would let me somehow accomplish:

```
$method = $_POST['method'];
$args = $methods[ $method ];
$method( $args );
```

Right now, my best bet is to load the arguments in the methods:

```
function do_something()
{
     $foo = $_POST['foo'];
     $bar = $_POST['bar'];
     ...
```

Comment: `func_get_arg()`/`func_get_args()`/`func_num_args()` with `call_user_func_array`? http://us2.php.net/manual/en/ref.funchand.php

Comment: Those first three go into the functions themselves and would actually add more overhead than what I'm doing now.

However, `call_user_func_array` is exactly what I'm looking for! I can just do: `call_user_func_array( array($this, $method), $args );` and it does exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you!